# Multiple identical random variables vs scaling a random variable by some constant

Tags: probability, random-variables

What is the difference between $X_1 + X_2 + ... X_n$ and $n \cdot X$, assuming $X_i$ is identical for every $i$ ?

Comment: What have you considered so far?

Comment: @Alborz actually this question resulted from my thinking about why $E[aX] = aE[X]$ is not applicable for a binomial random variable which is just $n$ Bernoulli random variables.

Comment: Of they are identical in the sense $X_i=X_j$, then there is no difference. If they are indepedent identically distributed (i.i.d.), then there is a difference. For binomial r.v. the underlying Bernoulli variables are not identical, but i.i.d.

Comment: @C614 could you elaborate further or provide a resource where I can learn more about this (specifically about independent identically distributed random variables)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say we have three dice, and represent their rolls by $X_1$, $X_2$, $X_3$. Assume that the rolls of the dice are independent of each other. Then $P(X_1 + X_2 + X_3 = 3)=(\frac16)^3=\frac1{216}$.

Now consider the random variable $3X_1$. What is the probability that $3X_1$ is $3$? It's just $\frac16.$

Clearly, these random variables behave very differently.

Intuitively, in general, it is much 'easier' for $nX_i$ to hit extreme values that $X_i$ can take.

For large $n$, $\sum_iX_i$ tends towards a normal distribution, whereas $nX_i$ retains $X_i$'s distribution, just scaled by a factor of $n$. For further reading, look into the Central Limit Theorem, probably the most important result in probability.